# Prolog apply predicate to list elements with maplist

Tags: prolog, maplist

I am trying to do a simple tranformation to all elemnts of a list:

```
 trans(X, M, Y):- Y is X*(-1) - M.
```

Then I am writing:

`maplist(trans, [1,2,3], NEW).`
I am getting a just a `true` instead of a new list..

Comment: Actually, I'm getting `ERROR: Unknown procedure: trans/2`, which is expected. You need to use `maplist/4`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a value to parameter like this for example:

`maplist(trans(5), [1,2,3], NEW)`

`Result: NEW =  [-6, -7, -8]`